# Is this "upspeak" or something else?

Tags: grammaticality, inflections

I am reviewing a book (fiction) where the following type of sentence occurs frequently:

- That dumb suggestion? That just made me angry. [That dumb suggestion just made me angry.]
- You and I? We’re in this together now. [You and I are in this together now.]
- And on that note? I expect to meet with you two again. [And on that note, I expect to meet with you two again.]
- The fewer things drawing attention to us? The safer our family. [The fewer things drawing attention to us, the safer our family.]

My first thought was that this is a type of [upspeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_rising_terminal), with a sentence fragment that is neither an actual nor an implied question ending with a rising pitch, as indicated by the question mark. However, this is not the stereotypical "Valley Girl" speech pattern, where a complete declarative sentence ends with a rising pitch. Instead, what could otherwise be a complete sentence is divided in two, with the first part of it emphasized by the rising pitch at the end.

Is this simply a variety of upspeak, or is this something different? Is there a name for this? Is this standard, albeit informal, English, or is it incorrect?

Comment: Is '[a type] ... with a sentence fragment that is neither an actual nor an implied question ending with a rising pitch' your own assessment of the four examples you give, or from Wikipedia? I see an implied question in each of the four fragments (other than _The safer our family._). 'What effect did that dumb suggestion have on me?' / 'Where does this leave you and me?' / ditto, but IMO odd to weird here. / 'What will the major outcome of having less things drawing attention to us?' // I find the first example fine, the second OK given decent context, but the rest stylistically questionable.

Comment: Yeah, the first two are pretty transparently questions. The other two, I have no idea. I wouldn't expect those to be either questions or upspeak (were they spoken). I think the author is not very good.

Answer (score 3):

I woud say you were right in your initial assumption. It does sound like upspeak (which is extremely common and for that reason, natural in spoken English)
Look at it this way:
That dumb suggestion? That just made me angry. [*You wanna know how I felt about that dumb suggestion? It just made me angry.*] - **Typical rhetorical question**

You and I? We’re in this together now. [*So where does that leave us? You and I are in this together now.*] - **Again the rhetorical question**

Of course, I may be totally off-target as I'm not familiar with the complete context. It seems the author is trying to replicate spoken language into text.

Comment: I'd add that the author is using a ham-handed technique for dramatic effect. Definitely overused in *safer...family*.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. "Overused" is un understatement ;)

Comment: The first two examples, considered on their own can, indeed be interpreted as questions of sorts, as has already been pointed out in the comments and the other answer. They however follow the same pattern as the other two, which cannot be interpreted that way, and that makes one wonder what the author's intentions really were. Incidentally, interpreting the first two examples as rhetorical questions is something different from interpreting them as upspeak (upspeak is a phenomenon that occurs in the sentences that are not questions at all, not even rhetorical ones).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you in finding this strange. I would definitely count this unnatural dialogue against the author in your review.

You don't say whether the sentences with question marks are in response to something another character has said (for example, mentioning a third character's 'dumb suggestion'). In that case, the questioning tone is plausible; but I find your last two examples quite unnatural.